# Python: Nested While Loops & Continue Looping

Tags: python, while-loop, nested

I need to ask the user if they would like to play a game, if the answer is `y` then the program will then ask you what game you want to play, if the user enters `n` or even enters they will be asked again till they enter `y`.

Right now I have the while loop accepting any answer. Anyone able to see what I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
playAGame = 'y'
while playAGame == 'y':
    playAGame = raw_input('Would you like to play a game? (y/n)? ')
    doAnother = 'y'
    while doAnother == 'y':
            print 'Chess'
            print 'Tic Tac Toe'
            print 'Tetris'
            print 'Count'
            print
            print 'Global Thermonuclear War'
            game = raw_input('Pick a game: ').lower()
            if game == 'chess':
                    webbrowser.open_new("http://www.pygame.org/tags/chess")
                    break
            elif game == 'tic tac toe':
                        webbrowser.open_new("http://www.pygame.org/tags/tictactoe")
                        break
            elif game == 'tetris':
                        webbrowser.open_new("http://www.pygame.org/project-Clone+of+Tetris-2125-.html")
                        break
            elif game == 'thermonuclear':

                        print "\nWouldn't you perfer a good game of chess?\n"
                        break
            elif game == 'count':
                        maxNumber = input('How High? ')
                        for maxNumber in range(maxNumber):
                                print maxNumber
                                break
            else:
                    print '\nI did not understand that!\n'
                    break
    # Ask user if they want to do another
    doAnother = raw_input('Do another (y/n)? ')
    print '\nThanks for playing!'
    print '\nGood Bye!'
```

Comment: What's the point of `playAGame = 'y'; if playAGame == 'y':`?! Also, note that you only ask the user if they want to play again if they played `count`.

Comment: if is suppose to be a while, but I'm still stuck...

Comment: Please cut this down to a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - most of the code is irrelevant. Also, clarify the behaviour you're expecting, and what happens instead.

Comment: Rather than using playAGame as a character, use a bool. For instance, name it `isPlaying = True` at the start and set it to false when you expect to quit. Or just use a break statement to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems in your code is that this line `doAnother = raw_input('Do another (y/n)? ')` should be indented so that it is in the inner `while` loop. Another problem is that your `doAnother` and `playAGame` variables seem to have the same purpose. You should restructure your code to remove one of them.

Comment: Isn't it already in the inner loop? *Scratches head* I need to have two loops.

Comment: @Jake No, it's in the outer loop. It is at the same indentation as the inner loop `while` statement, it needs to be indented further to be part of body of the loop.